# Program working with multithreading, hangs when using multiprocessing

Tags: opencv, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm practicing with multithreading and multiprocessing, and I tried to implement the same program using both approaches.
The idea is to have two parallel threads/processes: one reading frames from a webcam and sending them to a queue, the other ones retrieves them and displays them.

```py
import json
import queue, threading
from queue import Queue
import trigger_events
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2


class system_manager():
    def __init__(self, source):

        ## camera reader
        self.camera_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
        # self.cam_read = threading.Thread(target=Camera_Reader, args=(source, self.camera_queue))
        self.cam_read = mp.Process(target=Camera_Reader, args=(source, self.camera_queue))
        self.cam_read.daemon = True
        self.cam_read.start()

        ## module for managing triggers (user/mug position)
        # self.cam_display = threading.Thread(target=Camera_Display, args=(self.camera_queue,))
        self.cam_display = mp.Process(target=Camera_Display, args=(self.camera_queue,))
        self.cam_display.daemon = True
        self.cam_display.start()



def Camera_Reader(source, camera_queue):
    print("Cam Loading...")
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(source)
    print("Cam Loaded...")
    while(True):
        # print(f"frame: {counter}")
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # counter += 1
        camera_queue.put(frame)


def Camera_Display(camera_queue):
    counter_frame = 0
    while(True):
        try:
            print(f"\nFrame: {counter_frame}")
            frame = camera_queue.get()
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if (key == ord('q')):
                break
            print("Here")
            counter_frame += 1
            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        except camera_queue.Empty:
            print("Nothing in queue!!!")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    SM = system_manager(source=0)
```

The weird thing is that if I use threads for the two separate tasks, everything works fine.
On the other hand, if I assign them to different processes, the one supposed to be showing frames (Camera_Display) hangs...I get the output:

```
Frame: 0
Cam Loaded...
```

so, the print("Here") line does not get executed, and the process hangs during the first iteration of the while loop.
I'm assuming both approaches should be usable for this problem, I don't understand what is going wrong when I use multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not enough to replace Threads by Processes, you also have to use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `queue.Queue`. The latter is meant for Threads by default.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: That was not the cause of my problem, I solved it by using set_start_method("spawn").
However, when the processes finally started running, I did have to use mp.Queue, so you basically solved the next problem in line, thanks! ;)

Comment: I do not think changing the start method solved the communication problem, but of course it is good news that it works now.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself properly. The original problem was that the processes weren't even starting, which was fixed by using spawn as start method. Once I did that, I got another error, deriving from the use of queues (TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects)...I solved this latest one by using multiprocessing.Queue instead of queue.Queue

Comment: You wrote that there was output from both processes, but `print('Here')` was not executed. So the processes must have started, there was a communication problem from using `queue.Queue` instead of `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: My bad, there was an error in the import section, once I fixed that and used mp.Queues() everything went ok, even without spawning the processes. In my (partial) defense, the minimal example I posted was too minimal...in the real situation, I still need to use  set_start_method("spawn") to make the processes go. I suspect it might have to do with one of the processes using a deep learning library, which is implementing multiprocessing already...maybe this messes up the whole mechanism? I'll have to look into that..anyway, thanks!